# Replacing our existing computer inventory system

Tags: open-source, tool-rec

We've been using OCS-NG to gather our computer inventory for the past 2 years.  About 6 months ago, AVG Antivirus started picking up on the agent it uses to gather computer information as a "potentially harmful program".  We've placed that in our ignore list, but the agent no longer appears to be updating our database.  After much consideration and frustration trying to diagnose, I've decided to move away from OCS-NG as well as GLPI (with which it interfaces nicely).

I'm looking for a replacement for both of these applications, but primarily OCS-NG.  My requirements are:

- Open Source (preferably free)
- Windows/Linux inventory agents

I would like it if the system was able to be integrated with a helpdesk system such as OTRS or the like.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this moment there is no 'canned' asset discovery solution which has an out-of-the-box integration with OTRS.
However, OTRS is able to import CI data from CSV files. Also, we're hard at work cooking up a new SOAP/REST/JSON interface.

We're planning on integrating with asset discovery solutions, and would be open for people wanting to help with us on creating and testing the integration, and/or help from anyone working on FOSS asset discovery projects.

Comment: are there any projects you can recommend over OCS-NG that are FOSS?